# More efficient way to gather ripened mushrooms?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

I am having my progress stone-walled by a seemingly simple quest to gather 5 ripened mushrooms.

I understand that to get them I need to beat it out of the bugs carrying them but there simply don't appear to be enough of them actually carrying mushrooms to gather enough.

Is there some other way to gather them that I am missing or am I just having abysmal luck on the spawns?

Comment: Is your problem not spawning enough Altaroth or something else?

Comment: Not enough Altaroth carrying the mushrooms, they're mostly just empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait for the Altaroth to move to a mushroom spot and suck up mushrooms before killing them. When they spawn they haven't ingested anything yet.

Comment: Ok just watched that in action, you've saved me from ending by subquest several more times and rendering the Azuros extinct.

Comment: As a tip, pay attention to the quest dialog.  It tells you how to get these otherwise unobtainable drops.  There are other quests like this where you attack/kill a monster doing something specific.